# strpos() that not case sensitive for lowercase and uppercase

Tags: php, search

I am using `strpos()` for search method.. is it possible that it won't be case sensitive...

for example I have this one: this code will always return as `False`

```
$val = 'John Wrick';
$sval = 'john';
if(strpos($val, $sval) !== false){
   // code here
}
```

is it possible that will return the conditinal value into `True`?

Comment: have you tried `stripos`

Comment: @gadss please ark and up-vote the answer. it will help other, thanks.

Comment: No response from peoples asking question, even after asking. frustrating. deleting my answer

Answer (score 2):

you can use strtolower(), strtoupper()

but the best way is to use stripos()

```
$val = 'John Wrick';
$sval = 'john';
if(stripos($val, $sval) !== false){
   echo "blah blah blah";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [stripos()](http://php.net/stripos)

Or
use [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) :

```
$val = 'John Wrick';
$sval = 'john';
if(strpos(strtolower($val), $sval) !== false){
  echo "sdfsd";
}
```

see [live demo](https://eval.in/309121)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like so:

```
$val = 'John Wrick';
$sval = 'john';
if(strpos(strtoupper($val), strtoupper($sval)) !== false){
   // code here
}
```